# fetch во Vue compontents Nuxt

Tags: vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

Здравствуйте.

Использую `fetch` как указано в [документации](https://ru.nuxtjs.org/guide/vuex-store#%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4-fetch), для того, чтобы заполнить хранилище:

```
  async fetch ({ store, params }) {
    let { data } = await axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/messages')
    for (var item in data['_items']) {
      let message = data['_items'][item]
      console.log()
      store.commit('messages/add', message)
    }
  },
```

Но сталкиваюсь со следующей особенностью: когда я захожу на страницу в первый раз (по ссылке или при помощи адресной строки), то всё срабатывает как надо. Но когда я ухожу на другую страницу при помощи ссылок `vue-router`, а затем возвращаюсь на эту страницу (на которой отрабатывает `fetch`), то данные в `vuex` подгружаются вновь, а так как содержимое страницы строится исходя из данных в `vuex`:

```
  <ul>
    <li v-for="message in messages"> 
      <span class="message__text">{{ message.text }}</span>
      <span class="message__created">{{ message.created }}</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

то сообщения, соответственно, дублируются.

Как быть в этой ситуации?

На ум приходят костыльные решения, но я хочу найти DRY и KISS решение, которое будет идеальным в решении этой задачи.

Comment: Вы нашли решение?

Answer (score 0):

Возможно после вывода message нужно обнулить message в store. Только будьте внимательно с реактивностью.